# Why (and when) do I need to use parentheses after sizeof?

Tags: c, sizeof

The below fails to compile:

```
typedef int arr[10];
int main(void) {
    return sizeof arr;
}

sizeof.c:3: error: expected expression before ‘arr’
```

but if I change it to

```
sizeof(arr);
```

everything is fine. Why?

Comment: sizeof as an operator is not avaliable in ansi-c

Comment: @Kostya: my copy of K&R (the earliest description of the C language I have) is very far away and I can't check it now, but I'm 110% sure it describes `sizeof` fundamentally the same way C99 Standard does today. `sizeof` is available since before C was standardized by ANSI in 1989.

Comment: @Grim Your statement "sizeof as an operator is not available in ansi-c" is wrong. C90 has a section 3.3.3.4 "The sizeof operator". In C99, this moved to section 6.5.3.4.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

According to 6.5.3, there are two forms for `sizeof` as the following:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Since `arr` in your code is a `type-name`, it has to be parenthesized.

Comment: +1 and, just to reinforce that `sizeof` is an operator: the parenthesis "belong to" the type, not the operator.

Comment: @pmg:
Thanks for clarification! Yes, as you mentioned, the standard denotes
`sizeof` as an operator.

Comment: A7.4.8 in K&R, for retrogrouches like me.

Comment: @pmg: I don't think it's clear what the parentheses "belong to".  The syntax of the second form consists of three tokens and one non-terminal: `sizeof ( type-name )`.  But for the first form, you *can* write, for example, `sizeof(x)`, and though it looks like a function call (if `sizeof` weren't a keyword), it's really an operator applied to a parenthesized expression.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: What I mean is that `sizeof` is, syntactically `sizeof <SOMETHING>` as opposed to functions, for instance, to a `printf` which is `printf ( <SOMETHING> )`. The parenthesis belong to the `printf` but not to `sizeof`. When `sizeof` is applied to a parenthesized type name, I like to think of that as a cast of nothing -- "returning" just the type.

Comment: @pmg: You can certainly think of it that way, but I find it misleading.  The only real resemblance to a cast is that it has a type name in parentheses, and that's just a coincidence of syntactic convenience.  I prefer to think of `sizeof ( type-name )` as its own kind of expression.  (The standard calls it an operator, but `( type-name )` isn't really an operand in the usual sense.)

Comment: Just for fun: `sizeof(0)["abcdefghij"]` is `1`.

Comment: @melpomene A more common way to write `sizeof(0)["abcdefghij"]` is `sizeof("abcdefghij"[0])`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/

Answer (score 58):

That's the way the language is specified, type names must be parenthesized here.

Suppose the grammar looked like this:

`sizeof unary-expression`

`sizeof type-name`

Now, e.g. the following expression would be ambiguous:

```
sizeof int * + 0
```

It could be either `sizeof(int *) + 0` or `sizeof(int) * +0`. This ambiguity doesn't arise for unary expressions, as an asterisk appended to an expression isn't an expression (but for some type names, appending one, is again a type name).

Something had to be specified here and requiring type-names to be parenthesized is a way to solve the ambiguity.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's because you have `typedef`. If you remove it, it should compile.

Example from wikipedia:

```
/* the following code fragment illustrates the use of sizeof     
 * with variables and expressions (no parentheses needed),
 * and with type names (parentheses needed)    
 */
char c;
printf("%zu,%zu\n", sizeof c, sizeof (int));
```