# Comparing size of NULL macro with size of char

Tags: c, null, sizeof

I'm testing to see that the NULL constant does indeed occupy the size of a pointer:

```
ASSERT(sizeof NULL == sizeof(char*));
```

However, I accidentally wrote the following instead:

```
ASSERT(sizeof NULL == sizeof char);
```

That should have compiled, but instead it gave me the following error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘char’
```

The same happened after I enclosed `NULL` in brackets

```
ASSERT(sizeof(NULL) == sizeof char);
```

Isn't the NULL constant usually suppose to be defined by a macro which associates it to a pointer which is equal to 0? The statement was obviously false but as far as I see there was no syntactic error.
If that is true, why was I receiving a compilation error?

Comment: NULL is 0. So its size of int.

Comment: Type names must be enclosed in parentheses when they are the operand of `sizeof`.

Comment: In C NULL is usually (void *)0.

Comment: `NULL` may be defined as `0` or `(void*)0` or otherwise. There is no guarantee that it will have the same size as a pointer.

Comment: "This should have compiled"?! Why would you assert that?

Comment: sizeof() requires parenthesis per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894892/why-do-i-need-to-use-parentheses-after-sizeof

Comment: @PranitKothari C allows `NULL`, a _null pointer constant_, to be an `int` or a `void*`.  "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.".  As I read that, `NULL` could also be `unsigned` or `long long`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When the operand is a type name, it must be enclosed in parentheses": [C sizeof operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator)

In C, NULL is usually defined as

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

Comment: I think you mean `#define NULL ((void*)0)`

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - yep, sure.