# Sizeof const char* wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *lang = @"en";    
const char* ar = [lang UTF8String];
int size_of_array = (sizeof ar) / (sizeof ar[0]);
```

`size_of_array` is equal to `4` and `(sizeof ar) = 4` and `sizeof ar[0] = 1`.
Why? I think it (`size_of_array`) has to be `2`.

Comment: There is no variable `ar` in your code.

Comment: array name has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Your third line of code references an array "ar" that isn't declared anywhere in your post, and doesn't seem to relate to the code before it.

Also, the bit `sizeof ar[]` doesn't make much sense. That will give you the size of a single element in your `ar` array, whatever that is. So you are taking the size of the pointer variable ar, and dividing it by the size of one element in the `ar` array.

Are you trying to determine the memory size of the ASCII string lang_ch?

If so, then you want

```
int size_of_array = strlen(lang_ch) + 1;
```

That will give you the length of the string you get back, including the null terminator.

Comment: Minor remarks: 1) `sizeof(char)` is always one (per definition) - 2) `sizeof` is a keyword, not a function. It requires parentheses when used with a type, but not when used with an expression. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894892/why-do-i-need-to-use-parentheses-after-sizeof.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for clarifying the nature of sizeof. I was too lazy to go find my copy of K&R. I know that char is always size 1, but its a good habit to write `count * number_of_elements` type code when calculating the size of dynamically allocated structures, so I was following that pattern.

Comment: "sizeof(char) * lang_ch[0]);" makes less sense than the question's code. First, there's a stray parenthesis. Second, you multiplying the first character value by 1? How does that give the size of an array? You're likely to get 101, the UTF-8 value of "e", the first character of `lang`.

Comment: Oh lordy, you're right. I haven't used C strings in so long that I relapsed to PASCAL strings, where the first byte is a length-byte.

Comment: Remove the `[0]`. You're passing a `char` to something expecting `char*` (pointer to `char`).

Comment: Good lord. Time to just pack it in on this thread. <bows head in shame for the endless stream of stupid mistakes...>

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof ar` will get the size of the type `char *`, which is a pointer and so takes 4 bytes in memory.  You want to get the length of the string, so use the function `strlen` instead of `sizeof ar`