# Linked List using C - dynamic memory allocation to a node

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *new;
new = malloc(sizeof node);  // syntax error
new = malloc(sizeof(node)); // working fine
```

I am trying to assign memory to a new node dynamically using `malloc` function, my DOUBT is, why the first statement is giving syntax error? The only difference between the two statement is that in the second one node is inside brackets.

Comment: The type name is required brackets.

Comment: see [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) **A.2.1 Expressions (6.5.3)**

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894892/why-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-parentheses-after-sizeof)

Comment: please don't write `sizeof(type)`. Use `sizeof(*variable)` instead, for safety reasons. and most definitely do **NOT** call your variable `new`, it's a C++ keyword, and there are people who are trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler.