# How to add a struct to the end of an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs which is dynamically allocated. I would like to add new structs to the end of the array.

The struct defined as

```
struct book
{
    char *id;
    char *bookName;
    char *authorName;
    char *numOfPages;
    char *publishingYear;
    char *category;
} typedef t_book;
```

The array defined as

```
t_book* books= (t_book*)malloc(4*sizeof(t_book));
```

Comment: maybe increase the number `4`and that will do the trick ? mm

Comment: What does it mean "add new structs in the end of the array"? You have an array with exact 4 elements. Do you want to create 5th element or just set a value for 4th?

Comment: [realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)...?

Comment: You can implement a linked list with every node including a `t_book` element, or you can simply use `realloc`. Side note: You don't need to cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: I can easily increase the size of the array from 4 elements to 100 element (for example). but my problem:
after i once initialize the array with 4 elements. I'm not able to add another element at the end of this array (It has to be this array exactly- and not another array from the same type).

Comment: `books` is not an array.  It is a pointer to memory.  It can point to a memory location big enough for 4 books.  Later it can be re-assigned to  point to memory for 5 books.  With  `t_book b4[4];`, `b4` is an array.

Comment: @AmitLevy In C, once an _array_ is created, its size cannot be changed.  Your code does not use an array, but a pointer to memory and where it points to can be changed.

Comment: Look up the `realloc` function. It does pretty much what you want if you are careful with it.

Answer (score 2):

Re-allocate memory with `realloc()`

```
size_t new_book_count = book_count + 1;
//                              size of 1 book * book count
void *newbooks = realloc(books, sizeof *books * new_book_count);
// Successful ?
if (newbooks == NULL) {
  perror("Out of memory");
  return error;
}
books = newbooks;
// copy in new structure
books[book_count] = new_struct;
book_count = new_book_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
t_book* books;
books = malloc( 4 * sizeof *books); //Preferred way to do malloc
//At this point you want to add one in the end
t_book* bookstemp=realloc(books,5 * sizeof *books);
// temporary variable for the case where realloc fails not to loose data
if(bookstemp){
  printf("Realloc succeeded\n");
  books=bookstemp;
}
else
  printf("Realloc failed\n");
```

Comment: @chux : You're right, that was a bit loose.

Comment: I do not think`realloc(books,5*sizeof *t_book)` will compile.  Suggest `realloc(books,5*sizeof *books)`  see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5894892/2410359)

Comment: @chux : Indeed that was the intention, not just with this, with the `malloc` too..