# What type of parameter does sizeof accept?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s-%lu\t", argv[i], sizeof(argv[i]));
    }
}
```

I expect that `$./a.out int long` should give me

```
short-2 int-4 long-8
```

but instead I am getting

```
short-8 int-8 long-8
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: `argv[i]` has type "pointer to char" so you get the size of a pointer to char. There is no way to get the size of a user-entered string as if was a real C type. You may want to do `int a = 0; long b = 42; long long c = -1; printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof a, sizeof b, sizeof c);`

Comment: `sizeof` *is not a function!* It's a *prefix operator* (like unary minus). And, in particular, when passing a value to it you don't need to put parentheses around the value.

Comment: To get this to work you would need code like `if (!strcmp(argv[i], "int")) sz = sizeof(int); else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "long")) sz = sizeof(long)`...

Comment: @KonradRudolph *And, in particular, when passing a value to it you don't need to put parentheses around the value.*  [Not always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894892/why-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-parentheses-after-sizeof).  And I'd argue that because parenthesis are **required** to be used with `sizeof` in some situations, they should **always** be used.

Comment: [Why is sizeof considered an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714). And `sizeof` returns a `size_t` so [you must print it with `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15610053/995714), not `%lu`

Comment: @AndrewHenle But how does the Q you linked to countradict KonradRudolph's statement?

Comment: @AndrewHenle No, **always** true. You only need parentheses for *type names*, never for values. And contrary to you I argue that you should *only* use parentheses for type names, and never for values, precisely to disambiguate these cases (that's in fact what the parentheses are *for*, so you *can't* always use them, rendering your advice unworkable!).

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are some cases where parentheses are useful. For example `sizeof ((expression) + 0)` to get the size that would result from applying default argument promotions to some scalar `(expression)`. EDIT: make that "some integer `(expression)`" since it doesn't work for `(expression)` of type `float`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I mean, yeah, of course, use parentheses to disambiguate operator precedence. That rule applies generally, not just for `sizeof`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph How does having two different styles for using the same construct make code more readable and easier to understand?

Comment: @KonradRudolph So your rule should be "never for values unless you have to"! Also, you'd usually want to use parentheses when the operand is a macro parameter.

Comment: @IanAbbott That would make for some really hard-to-find bugs if you miss that "when you have to", now wouldn't it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Because the parentheses *have a purpose*: disambiguate between type names and variable names.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess so, but the same applies to other expressions where operator precedence has not been properly taken into account. Personally, sometimes I use parentheses and sometimes I don't, depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't understand the confusion. The rule is: "use parentheses exactly as you normally would inside an expression". Nobody puts parentheses around single identifiers (except in macros), so they shouldn't do this for `sizeof` either. For `sizeof` specifically, parentheses around an identifier should be reserved for type names. That's their purpose.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Given `char a`, what does `sizeof a + 1` mean?  Does it mean `sizeof( a + 1 )` or `sizeof( a ) + 1`?  If you **always** use parentheses when using `sizeof()` there's no ambiguity possible.  There's no object argument you can make for omitting parenthesis.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Please stop being disingenuous. In case this still isn't clear (despite me having repeatedly clarified it): my statement above concerned the case where `sizeof` is applied to a simple identifier, not when applied to a complex expression. And you are still wrong: you **cannot** always use parentheses, that's specifically why two forms of `sizeof` exist: in C (and C++), you can have overloaded type and variable names, that's why you might need to disambiguate them for `sizeof`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Personally, I often also omit the parentheses when the operand is a postfix expression.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` is not a function; it is an operator.

It gives you the size of the object, type or constant expression.
It will not give you the size of the type if you pass it as the string.

`sizeof("long")` will give you the size of the *string literal* `"long"` (i.e. 5) not the size of the type `long` (e.g. 8).

As `argv` is an array of pointers to `char`, `sizeof(argv[j])` will give you the size of the `pointer to char`.

Comment: "sizeof is not a function" has been mentioned twice now, with no explanation of why that is relevant to the OP's question (other than minor syntax quibbles).

Comment: @RobertHarvey does it hurt?

Comment: It doesn't help much.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP's question did mention the "c function sizeof()" originally before it was edited by others, so there is no harm pointing out that it isn't a function.

Comment: Since you already say that `sizeof` is not a function, please drop the parentheses if an object is the argument. You would not write `return (0);` or `x = -(23);`, would you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It is relevant because arguments to functions are processed differently from operands to operators. Arguments to functions undergo the default argument promotions (for functions without prototypes or for arguments corresponding to `...`) or conversion to the parameter type (otherwise). Operands to operators have different treatments depending on the operator. In particular, operands to `sizeof` do not undergo lvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, function-to-pointer conversion, or the integer promotions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Additionally, using the correct terminology aids communication. If one programmer to another said there was an error in the function call in a certain line of code, the other programmer would be looking for an actual function call and some error in it, not looking at the `sizeof` expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Only if you explain how it is relevant to the question asked.  Calling out an OP's error about the nature of sizeof is pointless if they can't tell the difference between a string literal and another type.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, Re "*Only if you explain how it is relevant to the question asked.*", No, those benefits are gained even without adding what 0 apparently believes would clutter their answer.

Comment: @Robert I would argue that correcting terminology, in a field where clear communication is paramount, is *always* appropriate even without any further benefits (this is still true, and arguably *more* true, with many definitions being ambiguous or vague, and subject to debate). I agree that explaining *why* the difference is relevant would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

> What type of parameter does sizeof accept?

The operand of `sizeof` may be an expression (particularly a *unary-expression* in the formal grammar) or a *type-name* in parentheses, per C 2018 6.5.3 1. Per 6.5.3.4 1, it shall not be applied to:

- an expression that has function type (example: `sin`),
- an expression that has incomplete type (example: `x` after `extern struct foo x;`, where `struct foo` has not yet been defined),
- an incomplete type (example: `int []`), or
- a bit-field member.

For `sizeof(argv[i])`, `sizeof` produces the size of `argv[i]`, which is a pointer to `char`. Applying `sizeof` to a string will not produce the size of the type named in the string (except by coincidence); it produces its result based on the **type** of the expression itself, not upon the value of the expression or anything it points to or contains.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare user input to `"int"`, `"long"`, etc you need to do it manually

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "int") == 0) {
        int dummy = 42;
        printf("size of int is %zu\n", sizeof dummy);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "double") == 0) {
        printf("size of double is %zu\n", sizeof (double));
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "long") == 0) {
        long int dummy = 42;
        printf("size of long is %zu\n", sizeof dummy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what's happening, is that the sizeof **operator** computes the size of the string that you input through `argv`. The problem is that `int` when typed in `argv` means nothing, it's just text for the program.

Of course you could implement your idea using `switch` or `nested conditionals` to check if argv[i] is equal to the name of the type and then return the result of sizeof on that type. Look at @pmg's solution for that.

But even though it'll do what you want it has it's limitations, only the types implemented can have their size computed, which I guess is not your what you're looking for.